# TFS Git build breaks after updating build definition

Tags: c#, git, tfs, visual-studio-2015

Our TFS build has broken following updating the XAML build definition. Changes included modifying the template and a few parameters. The trace is below

```
TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition [REDACTED]: 
Exception Message: Cannot set unknown member 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Git.GitPull.CheckoutSubmodules'. (type XamlObjectWriterException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteStartMember(XamlMember property)
   at System.Xaml.XamlServices.Transform(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlWriter xamlWriter, Boolean closeWriter)
   at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.FuncFactory`1.Evaluate()
   at System.Activities.DynamicActivity.OnInternalCacheMetadata(Boolean createEmptyBindings)
   at System.Activities.Activity.InternalCacheMetadata(Boolean createEmptyBindings, IList`1& validationErrors)
   at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivity(ChildActivity childActivity, ChildActivity& nextActivity, Stack`1& activitiesRemaining, ActivityCallStack parentChain, IList`1& validationErrors, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback)
   at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivityTreeCore(ChildActivity currentActivity, ActivityCallStack parentChain, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors)
   at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.CacheRootMetadata(Activity activity, LocationReferenceEnvironment hostEnvironment, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors)
   at System.Activities.Validation.ActivityValidationServices.InternalActivityValidationServices.InternalValidate()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers.ValidateWorkflow(Activity activity, ValidationSettings validationSettings)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildProcessCache.LoadFromXaml(String workflowXaml, TextExpressionImports textExpressionImports)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareRequestForBuild(WorkflowManagerActivity activity, IBuildDetail build, WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)
```

The build fails in the first few seconds as this is the process that is trying to retrieve the source. However, I cannot come to any conclusions as to why this error is happening. A Google search doesn't bring up anything useful.

TFS version 2013

Has anyone encountered this error and if so how did you fix it?

If I need to provide more information please ask.

Comment: I suspect that there are version numbers in the XAML file referencing the `14.0` object model (given you've listed the vs2015 tag). It's safer to do your workflow editing in the VS version that matches your TFS server. It looks like VS may have generated properties in your XAML (in your case `GitPull.CheckoutSubmodules` which are not supported by the older version of the build activity or don't even exist at all in the previous version.

Comment: You are correct @jessehouwing, I am referencing the `v14.0`, I am also referencing an older version. I am actually trying to have the TFSBuild server build the solution in parts, since some of the projects are compiled under `.Net 4.6.1` and others are still using `3.5`. To do this I added a second Build/Compile/Test section which points to a different `TFSbuild.proj` file which is a duplicate of the original with the exception of which target it is telling MSBuild to use.

Comment: Any idea why this keeps getting added to the build template? `<xmlns:sap2010="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2010/xaml/activities/presentation">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you modify the Build process template and therefore it’s no longer in sync with the build definition you may get TF215097 error.

@jessehouwing's suspicion makes sense. I can't find too many articles to elaborate this issue, but in [this MSND documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647548.aspx) mentions, if you want to edit a custom template, **You must use only Visual Studio 2013 to edit your build process templates** of TFS 2013.

Comment: I will accept your answer, the solution was that I needed to use and older version of visual studio (2013 in my case) since the TFS server was also on that version. Using a newer version of VS (2015) add some components to the `xaml` file which break when the server reads them (in my case it was `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Git.GitPull.CheckoutSubmodules` as well as some others once I removed that one). If you could expand these points just a bit, I will mark yours as the accepted answer